# Ejecutar macros excel desde Python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando ejecutar una macro de Excel desde Jupyter Notebook con Python con el siguiente código:

````
import win32com.client

if os.path.exists("MACRO.xlsm"):
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath("MACRO.xlsm"), ReadOnly=1) #create a workbook object
    xl.Application.Run("MACRO.xlsm!Módulo7.MACROMACRO")
    wb.Save()
    wb.Close(False) #close the work sheet object rather than quitting Excel
    del wb
    del xl ```
 
Pero me aparece el siguiente error:

com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-11606c2087a2> in <module>()
      2     xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
      3     wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath("MACRO.xlsm"), ReadOnly=1) #create a workbook object
----> 4     xl.Application.Run("MACRO.xlsm!Módulo7.MACROMACRO")
      5     wb.Save()
      6     wb.Close(False) #close the work sheet object rather than quitting Excel

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in Run(self, Macro, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4, Arg5, Arg6, Arg7, Arg8, Arg9, Arg10, Arg11, Arg12, Arg13, Arg14, Arg15, Arg16, Arg17, Arg18, Arg19, Arg20, Arg21, Arg22, Arg23, Arg24, Arg25, Arg26, Arg27, Arg28, Arg29, Arg30)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in _ApplyTypes_(self, dispid, wFlags, retType, argTypes, user, resultCLSID, *args)
    285 
    286         def _ApplyTypes_(self, dispid, wFlags, retType, argTypes, user, resultCLSID, *args):
--> 287                 result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
    288                 return self._get_good_object_(result, user, resultCLSID)
    289 

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ocurrió una excepción.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'No se puede ejecutar la macro "MACRO.xlsm!Módulo7.MACROMACRO". Puede que la macro no esté disponible en este libro o que se hayan deshabilitado todas las macros.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
````

Alguien me puede ayudar?
La al correr el código el archivo se me abre pero no ejecuta la macro (que esta a su vez llama a otras macros)
Gracias

Comment: Buen día, ¿Y si existen? ¿Están habilitadas las macros para ese archivo?

Comment: Están habilitadas y existen sí

Comment: Hola, ¿ la macro funciona sin problemas ?, ¿ probaste renombrar el file y la macro ?